# NSTimer stops after incrementing once

Tags: ios, uilabel, nstimer, object-state

I have an `NSTimer` which I want to update a label every second. My code is:

```
- (IBAction)OnClickEmergencyButton:(id)sender
{
    emergencyAlertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(emergencyTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [emergencyAlertTimer fire];
}

- (void)emergencyTimer
{
    int i = 0;
    _emergencyAlertTriggerTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ++i];
}
```

When I ran it, the label displayed "1" initially and then stopped.

I want the label to continuously count up every second, like "1", "2", "3", ...

Comment: Your code isn't 'safe' if you press the button multiple times...

Comment: Why are none of the answers using an instance variable?

Comment: @Wain yeah I also don't understand that.

Comment: @Wain: I didn't used instance variable, for keeping the variable "Scope" safe. If I put it as an instance variable, it can be accessed by other methods of the same class, if there is no need of that functionality, I think using a static variable will be better.

Comment: @MidhunMP, ok, but I'd say that should be pointed out in the answer as static variable applies those limitations

Comment: @Wain: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add my above comment to my answer

Comment: @Wain The button is hidden once it is clicked. So, i don't think multiple button clicks would be a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no issue with your timer. The issue is with the variable declaration inside the `emergencyTimer`, you declared it as a local variable. So each time when the timer fires the variable will be initialized to 0 again. So declare the variable as static, so that it can preserve the value.

Change the method like:

```
-(void)emergencyTimer
{
    static int timeValue = 0;
    _emergencyAlertTriggerTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++timeValue];
}
```

---

**Why static variable and Why not instance variable ?**

I didn't used instance variable, for keeping the variable "Scope" safe. If I put it as an instance variable, it can be accessed by other methods of the same class, if there is no need of that functionality, I think using a static variable will be better.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is with this code

```
int i=0;
```

Every time when timer method gets called, the integer `i` gets initialized and label will be displayed as "1" always.

Make this variable `global` or `static` to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `int i=0;` from your timer action method because it will always have a value of zero. You should be using an instance variable (`@property`) to store the `timerCounter` and increment that and use it to populate the label.

At some point in time you need to invalidate the timer. This is particularly important to do before you create a new timer and replace the reference to the old timer. Currently, if you press the button twice, you will then have 2 timers running and your label will increment twice a second...

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger timerCounter;

- (IBAction)OnClickEmergencyButton:(id)sender {
    [emergencyAlertTimer invalidate];
    emergencyAlertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(emergencyTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [emergencyAlertTimer fire];
}

- (void)emergencyTimer {
    _emergencyAlertTriggerTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.timerCounter];
    self.timerCounter++;
}
```

You should also invalidate the timer when the view is removed from display / deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

Always timer get called `emergencyTimer` but your value of `i` won't changed because it's an local variable, scope of `i` will remain at end of function call. Try this with static variable which remain globally...

```
-(void)emergencyTimer{
    static int i=0; // initialize at first time only..
    _emergencyAlertTriggerTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++i];
   if ( i == 100) 
       [ emergencyAlertTimer invalidate] // stop at certain condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly everyone is right you will only display a 0 no matter what you do currently so use an instance variable.

With regards to the only firing once, instead of [NSTimer fire] try this:

```
emergencyAlertTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(emergencyTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:emergencyAlertTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```